# Can you install the game on one drive and expansion packs on another?

Tags: the-sims-3

I gave my daughter a computer with a 128 Gigabyte SSD boot drive and some lager storage drives, so she could play Sims 3.

Sims 3 takes up a lot of space when you start adding expansions packs.

Is it posible to install the main game on the SSD and install expansion packs on one of the storage drives?

Comment: I'd suggest to use a program like [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) to find out which files exactly occupy so much space.

Comment: Did you install all the expansion packs? Because if you did, that would take up around ± 30 to 60GB. And I wouldn't recommend installing games on a 128GB SSD. That amount of space on a SSD is recommended for Windows and/or software.

Comment: The best workaround would be to just buy a extra HDD. You do not need the fastest nor the biggest so they should be relatively cheap.

Comment: SpaceSniffer is another alternative for disk space analysis

Comment: If you wish to respond to people in the comments, **please do so with a comment**, rather than by editing your post. It's significantly easier to follow that way.

Comment: Unionhawk, the site notes seen in a new comment window suggest that I edit the post instead.  So far adding further packs on a different drive seems to allow everything to work (after SIMS3 program code and one pack were first placed on the C: drive.)  I will build a symbolic link if I can, too, to save a little space on the boot avoiding save files there.  Thanks again for comments and suggestions, everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I don't "think" you can because all the expansions are installed and stored within the sims 3 folder on the PC when they install.  I would recommend getting a third party hard drive (External) and trying to get all the installs on there, it should fit easily.

Comment: Yes, sadly even if it were possible to get a hack going, maintaining it might be beyond the powers of a small girl.

Answer (score 0):

It is *possible*, but I don't recommend it.

I personally prefer installing The Sims 3 *outside* of `C:`, in a folder that gathers the files in one grouping. For example: the 'Base Game' goes into `E:\Games\The Sims 3\00-BaseGame`, and all expansions are installed into their own directories beside that directory, e.g., `E:\Games\The Sims 3\01-WA`, `E:\Games\The Sims 3\02-HELS`, and so on).

Do note that for The Sims 3, the majority of disk accesses are related to the loading of Game Objects, which are stored under `My Documents`, which usually resides in `C:`. So, by ensuring that the location of `My Documents` is in `C:`, you should gain significant speedup already.